# Improving a fit by changing constant parameters to functions

Tags: python, curve-fitting

I am trying to improve a correlation obtained for velocity in the downstream of a propeller (let us call it `U_d`). Using analytical approach and making some assumptions:

`U_d = U * (sqrt(A' + Ct.cos(a)^2 + 1) + 1) * ((B' + 0.5 * Ct.cos(a)^3) / (A' + Ct.cos(a)^2))`

Here, `U` is the wind velocity, `a` is the angle of attack and `Ct` is the propellers thrust. `A'` and `B'` are unknown values and they may be a function of other variables.
I have got a bunch of data for `U_d` for a combination of `U`, `Ct` and `a`, using CFD simulations. Now, guessing some sort of functions for each `A'` and `B'`, I actually did not find any algorithm to obtain the coefficients of those functions. For example, `curve_fit` of `scipy` in Python does not work, because not only `A'` and `B'`, but also `Ct`, `a`, and `U` are changing. Is there any suggestion on an algorithm to find some functions for `A'` and `B'`?

Comment: This sounds more like a fluid dynamics question than a Python question. :-)  I presume you have some data you are trying to fit? What does that data look like?

Comment: Is there any "cost" function you can define that you can call to minimize? There's several minimization functions in scipy and lmfit has some cool functions too.

Comment: ```scipy.optimize.curve_fit``` can be used just fine even if you have multiple non-constant independent (input) variables. In this case, you can feed a tuple containing all of your independent variables to the ```xdata``` argument and unpack this tuple within the model function that you are fitting.

Comment: Another note: you say that A' and B' may be a function of other variables; curve fitting procedures will generally assume that these values are constant and not try to find their dependency on variables as the search space would be huge. You should explicitly define A' and B' as function of the variables they might depend on.